# Performance hit on just overriding MeasureOverride?

Tags: wpf, performance, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have a derived class from WrapPanel that overrides the MeasureOverride method. I am building a skeleton / prototype of my app, first doing the view models and views to get a notion on screen flow etc. also to let other people provide feedback on the design. So its a very light weight app.

I noticed that clicking a particular button took a long time before bringing up the next screen, so I profiled the app (sampling). Next to the Startup method the MeasureOverride was the single method that took up the most time. This is my code:

```
public class GroupWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{
    public const double ItemSize = 120.0;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var numberOfRows = (availableSize.Height / ItemSize);
        var numberOfCols = (Children.Count / numberOfRows) + 1;

        var newSize = new Size(numberOfCols * ItemSize, availableSize.Height);

        return base.MeasureOverride(newSize);
    }
}
```

So I commented out the entire override and now it performed fast - the MeasureOverride was not in the list of methods that took up most of the time. The I just put in an override that did nothing but call the base class. Now the MeasureOverride was up there again, taking considerable time.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly means "I commented out the entire override". Is it a MeasureOverride with an empty body, or no MeasureOverride at all?

Comment: I removed my answer because it more a comment than answer. Anyways, interesting problem, give use more information please.

"Button took a long time before bringing up the next screen."

What is the next screen exactly? The WrapPanel is your next screen right? And it takes too long to draw/load it? You think it's custom measure logic fault for slow performance? Have you overridden arrange method as well?

Can you tell us after how many seconds you see your GroupWrapPanel?

Comment: @Clemens: "I commented out the entire override" => No method at all.

Comment: @hedgehog: The app consists of ViewModels that has hard coded items and Views displaying the (test) data. The app contains no real logic, just hardcoded dummy data. I use Caliburn.Micro for ViewModel-View matching and Conductor-Screen navigation. The button navigates to a new Screen. The button stays black for some time (about a second, less than two secs.) and then the new Screen is displayed. I used StopWatch to measure how fast Caliburn switches Screens (Conductor.ActivateItem) that was in the millis secs (<10).

Comment: So I started the profiler. I have NOT overridden the Arrange method, just the Measure (I just needed to restrict the WrapPanel). I did remove my logic completely - leaving nothing but a call-to-base. That still shows up in the perf-results.

Comment: Hi, take a snapshop of your performance profiler showing the results and post it here. Also tell us what profiler are you using?

Comment: Have been very busy. I have a download that demonstrates the problem. The app described in this blog post has the issue. Click on one of the device tiles. http://obiwanjacobi.blogspot.nl/2013/03/midi-console-user-experience-preview.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are suggesting that this:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    return base.MeasureOverride(newSize);
}
```

causes a significant slowdown, that seems highly unlikely. If you genuinely profile with and without that trivial override and notice different results, I think it's most likely that you have a "just my code" or similar setting on your profiler, or otherwise you've filtered such that you're not seeing the cost of `WrapPanel.MeasureOverride` when you were seeing `GroupWrapPanel.MeasureOverride`.

Whether the panel's measure really is taking up significant time is another matter, but is believable - I would suggest digging in the call tree and finding what calls contribute, you might find that some child item is expensive to measure.

Comment: This post is useless. You are telling him he doesnt know how to meausre performance.

Comment: This post is very helpful, as "you might find that some child item is expensive to measure" is most certainly the exact reason for the performance problem.

Comment: If there were children with expensive measure the app would still be slow even if you comment out measureoverride. The guy said its faster  without custom measureoverride hence your comment is also useless.

Comment: He comments the complete thing out. The complete method. Measureoverride is always called based on what type

Comment: Read the question. He says ENTIRE method.

Comment: LOL if you comment out the body you wont get any children displayed. Read about layouting before letting the boss out

Comment: Edited - code snippet was not even what I meant to write. Clearly there is not enough information to deduce the problem, but can you not agree that it is unlikely that a do-nothing override significantly degrades performance - layout is many times more expensive than virtual method calls. It's more likely that OP is measuring wrong, or has changed something else.

Comment: @NicholasW Right, let's wait until OP has answered weather he really had an empty MesaureOverride or not. I still suspect that it is one (or more) of the child elements that is expensive to measure.

Comment: While we wait and all that tell me how to put code in comment formatted pls

Comment: I really had a MeasureOverride method with just a call to the base impl. I totally agree that it looks like I'm measuring wrong. I have VS2010 and cannot find a 'just user code' setting in the Perf properties. I have even tested with one child item (before there were 14). It still shows up in the perf result the a significant amount of time was spent there...